# How do electrons know where to "drop to" when returning from an excited state?

Tags: electrons, spectroscopy

The Balmer series only shows electrons dropping to the energy level n=2 and the Lyman series only shows those that drop to n=1. How did they restrict the electron's energy transition so that the electrons only return to a specific energy level?

Comment: There has to be a hole (absence of an electron) in the given state for a different electron to drop into that state and release energy. You can create holes, e.g., by hitting the atom with x-rays. You can then observe the spectral lines of emitted x-rays (or softer radiation) as valence electrons drop down in energy to fill the "hole." If there are 1s holes you can see the Lyman series. If there are 2s holes you can see the Balmer series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scientists don't control the energy level where an electron lands. They observe different series based on what equipment they use to make the measurements. For example, if scientists only look at the visible light from glowing hydrogen, the only the Ballmer series will be observed. Other light from other series are being emitted, but that light is not detected due to the choice of instruments.

Comment: ahh I see, then how did Balmer know that his lines all had the same final energy state?

Comment: The energy of a given state is fixed for that state. Are you asking whether or not there are some hidden electronic states we don't know about somewhere? Certainly there can be subtle effects that split degenerate states, but I'm not sure if that is what you are asking about. If there we some *other* states with *other* energies then we would observe the transitions to (or between) those states as well which would result in additional observed spectral lines.  @joshuamason

Comment: @joshuamason He didn't know. He was able to come up with a [simple formula that matched all of the known lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series). Then, [Rydberg generalized the formula for all transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula). Finally, Bohr came up with the first [simple model of the atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) from which Rydberg's formula could be derived. Later developments in quantum mechanics would give the full behavior of hydrogen energy transitions.

Answer (score 5):

There's no restriction. An excited electron can drop from any state to any lower state. The full emission spectrum will therefore include lines that correspond to transitions to the $n = 1$ state, to the $n = 2$ state, the $n = 3$ state, and so on.

However, it is also true that if you look at the full spectrum of hydrogen, it consists of several non-overlapping sets of lines, each one with lines that become more and more closely spaced as they decrease in wavelength towards a limiting wavelength. We can therefore discuss each of these subsets of the full spectrum separately, as a "series" of spectral lines. And it turns out that each of these series corresponds to a set of transitions to one particular state ($n= 1$ for Lyman, $n = 2$ for Balmer, etc.) from various higher states.

Comment: An exercise in quantum mechanics (at the graduate level) is to compute the probabilities that a hydrogen atom with $n=3$ will emit a Balmer photon $3\to2$ versus a Lyman photon $3\to1$. This calculation is closely related to the calculation of the lifetime of the excited state.